# C++ Templates: Explicit specialization vs Complete specialization. Is it the same thing?

Tags: c++, c++17

In microsoft's documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/templates-cpp?view=msvc-170#template-specialization, it is said that `Specializations in which all parameters are specialized are complete specializations.`

but I also hear the cpp reference talking about explicit specialization here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Are "explicit specialization" and "complete specialization" two different terminology for the same thing?

Comment: There is a feature called partial specialization.  That is the other side of coin that complete specialization is on.

Comment: Seems like that, especially because Microsoft docs compares it to partial specialisation. Also, your cppreference link provides one more name, *full specialisation*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that they are referring to *explicit specialzations*, which is the term used in the standard. The term *full specialization* is also common.

The technical term *explicit specialization* may not be a good choice because the word *explicit* already is very overloaded. For example it can easily be confused with *explicit instantiation* or the `explicit` keyword.

The difference between explicit (or full/complete) specializations and partial specializations is however important and not just a matter of giving a specific variant of partial specialization an additional name. In contrast to a partial specialization, an explicit (or full/complete) specialization is not itself a template. So it basically follows all the rules of non-templates, including e.g. how `inline` and the ODR rule is applied. An explicit specialization also doesn't require any instantiation.